# Common Delete Modal Component in react with Reactstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, reactstrap

I am trying to create a common Delete Component and call from other components with  reactstrap.

Here is my DeleteModal

```
class DeleteModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal: false
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      modal: !prevState.modal
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Delete the item</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            Do you want to delete the item ?
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>yes</Button>
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>No</Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DeleteModal;
```

When the user click the YES button I need to return the ID of the item. So that I can know that delete confirm has been click.

Here is the other component from where I want to call the Modal

```
class Home extends Component {
handleDeleteClick(id) {
    console.log(id);
  }
}
```

handleDeleteClick is the method to call the modal also I need to pass the ID to the deleteModal component and when the user click on the YES button I need to get back the id from the DeleteModal.

How can I achieve this? I tried to research on this but not able to identify the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a bit the way you were doing, instead of sending the id to modal, you just save the `deleteID` on the state. It makes the DeleteModal more specific, it does not have to know any ID, it just let you know if you have to delete or not and the container component will manage that.

```js
class DeleteModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal: false
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      modal: !prevState.modal
    }));
  }
  
  deleteItem(){
    this.toggle()
    this.props.clickHandler()
  }

  close(){
    this.toggle()
    this.props.onClose()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Delete the item</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            Do you want to delete the item ?
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.deleteItem}>yes</Button>
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.close}>No</Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DeleteModal;



import DeleteModal from './DeleteModal'
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      deleteID: null
    };
    this.handleDeleteClick = this.handleDeleteClick.bind(this);
    this.onCloseModal = this.onCloseModal.bind(this);
    this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
  }

  handleDeleteClick() {
   //delete object
    this.onCloseModal() 
  }
  
  onCloseModal(){
    this.setState({deleteID: null})
  }
  
  openModal(deleteID){
    this.setState({deleteID})
  }
  
  return(<div><button onClick={()=> this.openModal(id)}>Delete</button>
    {deleteID && <DeleteModal clickHandler={this.handleDeleteClick} onClose={this.onCloseModal}/>}
  </div>)
}
```